# Boost Property Tree and Xml parsing Problems

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using `boost::property_tree`. The documentation is very vague and overall unhelpful for the most part. Looking at the source/examples didn't help that much, either.

What I'm wondering is the following:

```
<VGHL>
    <StringTable>
        <Language>EN</Language>
        <DataPath>..\\Data\\Resources\\Strings\\stringtable.bst</DataPath>
    </StringTable>
</VGHL>
```

How can I iterate over all the elements at the current level? If I do this:

```
read_xml(fin, bifPropTree);
VGHL::String tablePath;
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::wiptree::value_type &v, 
              bifPropTree.get_child(L"VGHL.StringTable"))
{
    m_StringTable->ParseEntry(v.second, tablePath);
}
```

In `ParseEntry` I try this:

```
VGHL::String langName = stringTree.get<VGHL::String>(L"StringTable.Language");
```

Results in an exception (not doesn't exist). I've also tried this:

```
VGHL::String langName = stringTree.get<VGHL::String>(L"Language");
```

Same problem.

From my understanding when I call `ParseEntry` I am passing a reference to the tree at that node.

Is there any way to deal with this, when I have multiple entries of `StringTable` using property tree?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ParseEntry receives a reference to each of the children nodes of the current level. So, you cannot ask the values using the node name, because you already have a child node. The node name is stored in *v.first*.

You can iterate  over all the elements at a given level using *get_child* to select the level and then *BOOST_FOREACH* to iterate. Each iterator will be a pair representing the name of the node and the node data:

```
using boost::property_tree::wiptree;

wiptree &iterationLevel = bifPropTree.get_child(L"VGHL.StringTable");
BOOST_FOREACH(wiptree::value_type &v, iterationLevel)
{   
  wstring name = v.first;
  wstring value = v.second.get<wstring>(L"");
  wcout << L"Name: " << name << L", Value: " << value.c_str() << endl;
}
```

This code would print:

> Name: Language, Value: EN
>
> Name: DataPath, Value: ..\\Data\\Resources\\Strings\\stringtable.bst

If you do not want to iterate, you can select the node level and then look for the nodes using their name:

```
wiptree &iterationLevel = bifPropTree.get_child(L"VGHL.StringTable");
wstring valueLang = iterationLevel.get<wstring>(L"Language");
wstring valuePath = iterationLevel.get<wstring>(L"DataPath");
wcout << valueLang << endl << valuePath << endl;
```

This code would print:

> EN
>
> ..\\Data\\Resources\\Strings\\stringtable.bst

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the property tree, but probably will as it looks nifty. A few quick observations though:

Should not the template parameter of get be the same as the return type?

VGHL::String langName = stringTree.get(...);

But this is most likely not a problem here, as this would have resulted in compile-time error.

Not sure if L"VGHL.StringTable.Language" argument works?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the that out im basically in the process of merging codebases. 

VGHL and Ludo::String both are typedefs of std::wstring :)

That wasnt the problem :(

Comment: Also i just checked, that doenst work ether. 

You can use iterators, but they will always be on the current level.